# Django==1.10.dev20160410181954' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a Django Project. I installed **Django 1.9.0** using **python pip** and I'm using **python 2.7**.

Whenever i try to create a new project i am getting an error:

```
django-admin startproject myproject
```

**Error:**

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'Django==1.10.dev20160410181954' distribution was not found and is required by the application
django-admin startproject myproject
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this command ?

`cd /usr/local/bin`

`sudo chmod +x django-admin.py`

and then Try creating a project again.

Comment: Thanks it helped.. but don't know what was the problem ? Is it with permission issue only

Comment: Yes, it was permission issue.